# Replace onmicrosoft.com with b2clogin.com URL for MS Dynamics 365 Portal

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, azure-ad-b2c, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-portals

Microsoft recently issued documentation for redirect URL's to use the newer b2ctenantname.b2clogin.com URL instead of the login.microsoftonline.com which will eventually be depreciated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin

I currently have an MS Dynamics 365 portal successfully set up to use Azure B2C which uses the microsoftonline.com URL as part of the login process.

Albeit, when I amend our dev environment to switch to the b2clogin.com URL's as documented, I see 404 errors.

After raising a call with Microsoft, I get this response; "I have confirmed with our Dynamics 365 team that since the login.microsoftonline.com is the link provided in the official Microsoft article, then probably the use of b2clogin.com hasn’t been implemented yet."

I'd like to reach out to the community and see if anyone else has successfully set up the b2clogin.com domain for the login process for the Dynamics 365 Portal before I continue troubleshooting?

Comment: Have you set the ValidateAuthority property to `false`?

Comment: @SunnySun Thank you for the quick reply. Where do I set this in MS Dynamics 365? I have a custom setting presently that did refer to login.microsoftonline.com/[tenantid]

Comment: You could edit it in your in the Startup. Auth.cs of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While configuring MS Dynamics 365 to work with B2C (hope you only configured the system), you need to give authorize URL.
URL looks like: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/{Tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp](https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/cpimtestrk.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp)

Now to make that support with **b2clogin**, you need to update the URL which you configured at MS Dynamics 365. 
URL looks like: https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp

Comment: Thank you @Ramakrishna - the authority URL in MS Dynamics settings did need the oauth2 element. I copied the endpoint available in one of my B2C sign up policies.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Sorry, I forgot to say it worked after updating! :)